# Debugging jsp's using embedded jetty

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, embedded-jetty

How to debug jsp pages in a Dynamic web project using embedded Jetty server in Eclipse ?

I even tried to use Eclipse WTP... But no use

Quick help is very much needed. Even bit of clues will be very helpful

Well I am using Maven, where I have Jetty-Maven plugin. And I will run app as Remote Java App in Eclipse to DEBUG. In this way I could debug .java files, But I am unable to place breakpoints in .jsp files. I am not sure where the converted .jsp files into servlet files are stored by Embedded Jetty in my PC.

I downloaded WTP in eclipse. And ran my App in debug mode as Reomte Java App, tried to place breakpoint. Unable to place breakpoint with WTP.

My goal is to Debug .java and .jsp files. (Running as remote java app is not my goal, I can change it if possible)

Comment: see [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+with+the+Maven+Jetty+Plugin+inside+Eclipse)

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you *have* tried already?  This is a .jsp file in a Dynamic Web Project, right?  It should be as simple as right-clicking on it and telling it to Debug on a Server.